# Retrofit POST with two multidimenional arrays, how to send?

Tags: retrofit

I have this API and I need to send some data to it as follows:

```
www.abc.com/orders/new?items[][id]=1001&items[][quantity]=2
```

So I have to pass in these arrays

```
items[][id]=1001
items[][quantity]=2
```

If there are multiple items, it should look like this

```
items[][id]=1001 & items[][quantity]=2 
& items[][id]=1002 & items[][quantity]=3
```

So this is the problem I am having because I am aware that @Query can accept arrays **but the arrangement needs to be element of ids first and then element of quantities**. I cannot have all ids first and then quantities which is what happens.

```
@POST("/orders/new")
void send(@Query("items[][id]") String...ids, @Query("items[][quantity") String...quantity)
```

Please note I omitted the callback for simplicity.

I have also tried with lists, whereby the entire list contains all the needed information in the correct arrangement but then came the problem of only having a single @Query annotation i.e. "items[][id]" and "items[][quantity]"

Answer (score 0):

Use `@QueryMap`. It is like a HashMap. From [retrofit documentation](http://square.github.io/retrofit/), we have this:

> For complex query parameter combinations a Map can be used.

```
@GET("/group/{id}/users")
List<User> groupList(@QueryMap Map<String, String> options);
```

So, in your case, the key of the map will be the id, and the value will be the quantity.